# How to seed join table data from yaml file through seed.rb in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add to my seed.rb the ability to load data onto a join table for my ROR 3.2.5 application.

I have two models: Saft.rb and Keyword.rb, which I would like to join.

```
class Saft < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :keyword, :join_table => "safts_keywords"
end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :word
  has_and_belongs_to_many :saft, :join_table => "safts_keywords"
end
```

I seed datasets for both from a yaml file, such as from: keywords_list.yml

```
---
  - word: "12"

  - word: "34"
```

The corresponding part of my Seed.rb:

```
keywords_data = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('db/seeds/keywords_list.yml'))
keywords_data.each do |keyword|
    h = Keyword.find_or_initialize_by_word(keyword['word'])
    h.save
end
```

Now I would like to seed the initial dataset for the join table from a yaml file too. (safts_keywords.yml)

```
---
  - saft_id: 1
    keyword_id: 2
```

When I try to load the data through:

```
# Load the Join Table
safts_keywords_data = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('db/seeds/safts_keywords_list.yml'))
safts_keywords_data.each do |saftkeyword|
    h = SaftKeyword.find_or_initialize_by_saft_id(saftkeyword['saft_id'], 
    :keyword_id => saftkeyword['keyword_id'])
    h.save
end
```

I get:

> .
> .
> .
> ** Invoke db:structure:load_if_sql (first_time)
> ** Invoke db:create 
> ** Execute db:structure:load_if_sql
> ** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
> ** Execute db:seed
> ** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
> ** Invoke environment 
> ** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
> rake aborted!
> uninitialized constant SaftKeyword
> /Users/Stephan/Development/REPRO/APP/db/seeds.rb:99
> /Users/Stephan/Development/REPRO/APP/db/seeds.rb:97:in `each'
> /Users/Stephan/Development/REPRO/APP/db/seeds.rb:97
> .
> .
> .

How can I get this to work?

Edited:

I created the join table through a migration. It is named "safts_keywords", but Saft_Keyword does not work either in the seed.rb.

Comment: Silly question, but did you create the `SaftKeyword` table?

Comment: My join table follows the Rails migration and is named "safts_keywords", but I tried Saft_Keyword as well in the seed.rb to no avail. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @jvillian except in a ["HABTM"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) join in which case it is plural_plural. You should load through the models `Saft` and `Keyword` or create a model `SaftKeyword`.

Comment: I used "$rails g migration CreateSaftsKeywordsTable" to create the join table.

Comment: @engineersmnky. You mean I should populate my join table though the models? How would my seed.rb be?

Comment: I would try using `SaftsKeyword`.

Comment: Thank you all! I created a model "safts_keyword.rb" and used "SaftsKeyword" in the seed. Now everything is seeding as it should!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HABTM join tables do not usually have a model associated with them as they are simply join tables and nothing else.

That means these relationships would be established from one side or the other. Given my assumption that a `Saft` is more likely to have multiple `Keywords` I would go about this as follows.

I have no idea what a `Saft` is but if you know their ids I would recommend the following:

```
  1: 
    - keyword1
    - keyword2
    - keyword3
  2:
    - keyword2
    - keyword4
```

Then your seed file as:

```
  safts_keywords_data = YAML.load(Rails.root.join('db/seeds/safts_keywords_list.yml'))
  safts_keywords_data.each do |saft_id,keywords|
    saft = Saft.find(saft_id)
    saft.keywords << keywords.map do |key| 
      Keyword.find_or_create_by(word: key)
    end 
  end
```

If there is a clearer way to locate a unique `Saft` I would recommend that just from a readability standpoint but this should give you a clearer picture.

Comment: Thanks. A Saft is a magazine, each edition is defined by a series of keywords. Keywords can be associated with multiple issues of the magazine on the other hand. For this reason I have HABTM from both sides. Although it is currently seeding with the additional model, I will try your solution as soon as possible.

Comment: I checked it out and it works marvellously, although, since I have to use Ruby 1.8.7, I have to change "word: key" into ":word => key". But in my case the keywords table has "id", "keyword" and "description" rows, how can i push additional rows through the association onto the keyword table with this solution?